# Best way to store data about problems in fields of filled form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, forms

As I am writing my program by PHP programming language and Mysql DB in WordPress CMS, I built a plugin to create and handle a customize form in a special workflow to the needs of our customer.

After form being filled by the user, one of the editor users of the site would check the data of the filled form and validate them.
The screen shot of the validation page that is show to the editor users is like this.

[image]

As you see I fetch data of the form from Data Base and print them to the editor users to validate them. At first all the field are display in green background. By using jQuery I give the editor users the ability to click on the filled that has problem and change the color of the field to red. like the below screen shot.

[image]

My question is, how could I store the data about which fields are filled with wrong data (The field that are showing with red background) and use this kind of meta data to create an edit page for end user to correct that fields?

Of curse there are a lot of way to do that. The easiest but in my idea not optimize way is to add Boolean fields match to the form fields in Data Base and submitting hidden field according to that Boolean fields to store the information that each field is correct(TRUE) or not correct(FALSE).

The forms that I am working on have about 174 field that most of them are varchar(254). So the size of data that is storing in data base is huge and I don't wanna make it larger.

Ultimately could you please help me. Is there any other way to store the jQuery actions of the editor users and show that stored data to end users.

I am looking for your help.
Bests.

Comment: you will need a boolean field in your database table besides the inputs from the users

Comment: already I have 174 field so if I add a boolean field for each field my table would have 348 field. So in my idea it may increase the size of data in data base.

Comment: boolean's aren't big lol:)

Comment: and why do you have 174 field ?

Comment: The number of field is too much just the number of fields are extremely high

Comment: you need to retractor you database then

Comment: what do you mean by retractor?

Comment: split the table into multiple ones